# Problems deeplinking out of the Salesforce App on Android

Tags: salesforce1-app, cordova, deep-linking

I have an Cordova mobile app that I want to be able to deeplink to from the Salesforce App. I am currently using Branch.io for the deeplinking. The problem is that when I click the deeplink from within the Salesforce App, it opens my app as a window inside of the Salesforce app instead of actually taking me to my app. I asked about this in [a Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884913/prevent-deeplink-from-being-opened-within-the-browser-of-the-originating-app) and the answer was its probably the Salesforce App that is preventing you from leaving it. Is there something I can do to prevent my app from opening inside the Salesforce App? It works fine on iOS but not in Android.

Comment: Can you share your deep linking code snippet here? I've done deep linking in several of my apps and may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my [Stack Exchange Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105464/2079907):

What actually definitively resolved this was going into the AndroidManifest.xml and setting android:launchMode="singleTask" on my main activity.

I know that in the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode) it says singleTask is not recommended. I believe that's because it prevents you from going back but we take over the functionality of the hardware back button so that's not relevant. Also according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23866656/2079907), it seems like the right thing to do in our context.